# Nginx: resolve lists from environment variables into configuration file

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm using Nginx open source Docker image, and I'd like to have a method to pass, with environment variables, a list of servers.

These servers have to be passed to an `upstream` entry, but here is my question: exists a method for don't have to pre-determinate the number of servers?

I'd like a way for build a generic image, so that if I want to load balance my upstream to two, three, or any other number of servers, I only need to update my environment variables in docker compose with something like this:

```
    environment:
      - Nginx_UpstreamServers_0=myhost0
      - Nginx_UpstreamServers_1=myhost1
      - Nginx_UpstreamServers_2=myhost2
      # Add more if needed
```

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Not sure if I got it, do you want to have a way to set N upstreams depending on how many `Nginx_UpstreamServers` env vars you have?

Comment: Correct, named for example as elements of an array.